# Mongo Mapper & Rails - Queries suddenly taking > 100 ms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, heroku, homebrew

I swear that within an hour queries in mongo went from 0.3 ms per line to > 100 ms per line.  I added ZERO data to mongo within that time, and I've made no changes to the database, the gem file, or the rails controllers - just changing some of the CSS in the view.  Nothing that talks to the database.

Here is some example output:

```
MONGODB (121.1ms) creative_development['admins'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('518b762e89651a0389000013')}).limit(-1)
MONGODB (121.6ms) creative_development['$cmd'].find({"count"=>"customers", "query"=>{:merchant_id=>"518b762e89651a0389000013"}, "fields"=>nil}).limit(-1)
MONGODB (249.7ms) creative_development['customers'].find({:merchant_id=>"518b762e89651a0389000013"}).limit(40).sort([["first_name", "asc"]])
MONGODB (244.8ms) creative_development['customers'].find({:merchant_id=>"518b762e89651a0389000013"}).limit(40).sort([["first_name", "asc"]])
  Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (0.2ms)
MONGODB (121.5ms) creative_development['companies'].find({:_id=>"0"}).limit(-1)
MONGODB (131.2ms) creative_development['jobs'].find({:customer_id=>BSON::ObjectId('51b7890a9727912430000022')})
MONGODB (122.1ms) creative_development['jobs'].find({:customer_id=>BSON::ObjectId('51b7890a9727912430000022')})
MONGODB (120.9ms) creative_development['companies'].find({:_id=>"0"}).limit(-1)
```

Here is what it looked like before:

```
MONGODB (0.4ms) creative_development['customers'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('51ddf5969727913cf8000424')}).limit(-1)
MONGODB (0.4ms) creative_development['admins'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('51ddbd6b972791243d0000f1')}).limit(-1)
MONGODB (0.4ms) creative_development['jobtypes'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('51ddcff69727912dfe000001')}).limit(-1)
MONGODB (0.4ms) creative_development['jobpriorities'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('51a7d01289651a3b100000e5')}).limit(-1)
MONGODB (0.4ms) creative_development['customers'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('51e4a6c797279171bc000004')}).limit(-1)
MONGODB (0.5ms) creative_development['admins'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('51ddbd6b972791243d0000f1')}).limit(-1)
MONGODB (0.4ms) creative_development['jobtypes'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('519bff2e89651a32af000001')}).limit(-1)
MONGODB (0.4ms) creative_development['jobpriorities'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('51b782db972791212c0000e6')}).limit(-1)
MONGODB (0.4ms) creative_development['customers'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('51e7448997279123e6000001')}).limit(-1)
MONGODB (0.3ms) creative_development['admins'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('51ddbd6b972791243d0000f1')}).limit(-1)
MONGODB (0.3ms) creative_development['jobtypes'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('519bff1389651a32d800002b')}).limit(-1)
```

The query:

```
@all_customers = Customer.where(:merchant_id => session[:admin_id].to_s)

respond_to do |format|
        format.html do # index.html.erb
          @all_customers = @all_customers.sort([sort_column,sort_direction]).paginate(:per_page => 40, :page => params[:page])
        end
```

The sort part:

```
  def sort_column
    Customer.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "first_name"
  end

  def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
  end
```

Here is the same page, same login, same db data on Heroku:

```
2013-07-28T03:59:31.829330+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by CustomersController#index as HTML
2013-07-28T03:59:31.832789+00:00 app[web.1]: MONGODB (2.7ms) live-heroku['admins'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('51b0388697279164a4000001')}).limit(-1)
2013-07-28T03:59:31.839820+00:00 app[web.1]: MONGODB (4.5ms) live-heroku['$cmd'].find({"count"=>"customers", "query"=>{:merchant_id=>"518b762e89651a0389000013"}, "fields"=>nil}).limit(-1)
2013-07-28T03:59:31.896128+00:00 app[web.1]: MONGODB (55.7ms) live-heroku['customers'].find({:merchant_id=>"518b762e89651a0389000013"}).limit(40).sort([["first_name", "asc"]])
2013-07-28T03:59:31.951921+00:00 app[web.1]: MONGODB (13.8ms) live-heroku['customers'].find({:merchant_id=>"518b762e89651a0389000013"}).limit(40).sort([["first_name", "asc"]])
2013-07-28T03:59:32.126152+00:00 app[web.1]: MONGODB (7.7ms) live-heroku['admins'].find({:_id=>BSON::ObjectId('518b762e89651a0389000013')}).limit(-1)
2013-07-28T03:59:32.127529+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered shared/_header.html.erb (9.7ms)
2013-07-28T03:59:32.146588+00:00 app[web.1]: MONGODB (14.2ms) live-heroku['companies'].find({:_id=>"0"}).limit(-1)
2013-07-28T03:59:32.151084+00:00 app[web.1]: MONGODB (2.4ms) live-heroku['jobs'].find({:customer_id=>BSON::ObjectId('51b7890a9727912430000022')})
2013-07-28T03:59:32.191671+00:00 app[web.1]: MONGODB (2.4ms) live-heroku['jobs'].find({:customer_id=>BSON::ObjectId('51b7890a9727912430000022')})
2013-07-28T03:59:32.233914+00:00 app[web.1]: MONGODB (9.8ms) live-heroku['companies'].find({:_id=>"0"}).limit(-1)
2013-07-28T03:59:32.238298+00:00 app[web.1]: MONGODB (2.2ms) live-heroku['jobs'].find({:customer_id=>BSON::ObjectId('51b78a4e97279123fd000255')})
```

Heroku is pulling from a Mongo Lab instance.

My local environment(s):

MacBook Air this year (Haswell CPU, i5) and a Mac Mini circa 2012.

On both of these environments - the Mongo performance was 0.2 ~ 0.5 ms locally.  And then suddenly, really with no database changes, no gem upgrade, no controller or model changes in the Rails app, they just freaked out.

There is ONE thing I can imagine - I did a brew update on both of them within the past few days.  However - the performance did not decrease immediately after the brew update in either case.  I didn't 'timestamp' it in my brain, but there was a huge interval (hours) between the brew update and the slow-down.  In the case of the Air it was days.  The Mac Mini I don't remember exactly.

Does anyone have any ideas at all about why Mongo would suddenly just freak out like this?

Comment: Have you tried using `.explain()` on your queries from a console to see what's going on with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Son of a @#(%&@ it was my mongo.yml file that had a default database configured which WASN'T my localhost.

I have no idea when that changed - I was so focused on GIT history that I didn't bother checking in this file.